# Spring + JAXB integration : Class has two properties of the same name

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb

I am facing problem in **generating WSDL**. I want to create **SOAP web service** which generate **json string**. Below pojo classes are referenced from another web project into my web service project. I write generated json string on **servlet response** object which is created by using **WebServiceContext** & it is annotated with @Resource annotation.

I also tried to **debug** web service method (parameterized annotated with @WebParam), pojo but project is not starting in debug mode. Before calling web method it **throws exception** for all fields :

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 15 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "result"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public portal.common.ejb.LoginResult portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.getResult()
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private portal.common.ejb.LoginResult portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.result
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
Class has two properties of the same name "userInfo"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public portal.common.ejb.UserDTO portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.getUserInfo()
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private portal.common.ejb.UserDTO portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.userInfo
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
Class has two properties of the same name "notifications"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public java.util.List portal.common.ejb.LoginResult.getNotifications()
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResult
    at private portal.common.ejb.LoginResult portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.result
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private java.util.List portal.common.ejb.LoginResult.notifications
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResult
...
```

I am using **jaxws-ri-2.2.8**, **jaxws-json-1.2**, **jaxws-spring-1.9**, **xbean-spring-3.9** & **spring-framework-4.0.3.RELEASE-dist**.

**NOTE :** I am not much familiar with web services, so please be polite & patient.

**POJO**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LoginResponse {

    private LoginResult result;
    private UserDTO     userInfo;
    // Getter/setter
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LoginResult {

    private List<String>    notifications;
    private boolean         success;
    // Getter/setter
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDTO {

    private String  eMail;
    private Integer externalIdentifier;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastLoggedIn;
    private String  lastName;
    private String  phone;
    private Integer role;
    private String  status;
    private String  title;
    private int     userId;
    private String  userIdentifier;

    // Getter/setter
}
```

**Refered Doc:**

I also refer below link to solve the error

[JAXB's @XmlAccessorType - @Blaise Doughan](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html)

[Jaxb, Class has two properties of the same name - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768544/jaxb-class-has-two-properties-of-the-same-name)

[IllegalAnnotationsException: Class has two properties of same name - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392235/illegalannotationsexception-class-has-two-properties-of-same-name) , etc.

I tried all examples given by @Blaise Doughan. All works fine in Java application & Web app too. Also tried to generate wsdl & it generated & print output xml on console.

**Can anybody point out what's wrong in my pojo classes ?  I spend so much time on this but no luck. What should I have to do to get off this error ?**

**EDIT :**

I also **tried @XmlTransient** annotation on getter method & **@XmlElement** annotation on all fields but, same issue.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What if you comment the annotation XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) ?

Comment: Same problem occurs on commenting XmlAccessorType annotation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default JAXB treats the public properties (get/set method pairs) as mapped.  If you also annotate the corresponding field (instance variable) you will get this exception.

If you annotate your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` then JAXB will treat the fields as mapped.  If you also annotate the corresponding property you will get this exception.

**Examining the Stacktrace**

In the stacktrace you can see that the JAXB impl is complaining about `LoginResult.getNotifications()` and `LoginResult.getNotifications()` both being mapped.

```
Class has two properties of the same name "notifications"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public java.util.List portal.common.ejb.LoginResult.getNotifications()
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResult
    at private portal.common.ejb.LoginResult portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse.result
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private java.util.List portal.common.ejb.LoginResult.notifications
    at portal.common.ejb.LoginResult
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB and accessor types on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thanks for replying @Blaise Doughan. I removed XmlRootElement XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotations from LoginResult & UserDTO classes. It works fine now & my WSDL is generated. I am so happy to see WSDL. Thanks a lot.